# InfluxDB count distinct fields

Tags: influxdb, grafana

For example, given a field that holds URL paths (/some/path), is there some way to count each unique field such that we get a column holding the count?

Example output:

`time                   path       count
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z   /             12
2015-08-18T00:00:00Z   /api          52`

Making the path field a tag is obviously not a good idea as it can contain arbitrary and variable data, increasing cardinality a lot.

`SELECT count(path) AS path FROM "line" GROUP BY path`
Seems like it should work, but doesnt

Comment: You can not group by field in InfluxDB because fields are not indexed. Only grouping by tags/timestamp is allowed.